# Kafka tools won't start on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, software-installation

I Installed kafkatools from http://www.kafkatool.com/download.html in Ubuntu 18.04. The Installation is OK, but when I clicked on it, it does nothing. I installed multiple times on different devices, but I really don't have any idea what is happening.

First I installed openjdk-8-jdk, kafkatools, and after that I installed zookeeper and kafka, and I removed kafkatools and reinstalled it, but the issue persists.

Comment: You have openjdk-8-jdk installed as the default JDK with `sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk`, right?

Comment: Tnx for responding, Yeah I installed it.

Comment: I Installed it too, but First I installed kafkatools and after that, I installed zookeeper and kafka, but I removed kafkatools and reinstalled it but the issue persists

Comment: Does Kafka work from the terminal?

Comment: karel the issue resolved Thanx for helping , I removed java and then reinstalled it, it working now !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kafka is a distributed streaming platform. It is useful for building real-time streaming data pipelines to get data between the systems or applications. Another useful feature is real-time streaming applications that can transform streams of data or react on a stream of data. This answer will help you to install Apache Kafka on Ubuntu 16.04 and later.

#### 1. Install Java

Apache Kafka required Java to run. You must have Java installed on your system. Execute the below command to install default OpenJDK on your system from the official Ubuntu repositories. You can also install the specific version of from [here](https://tecadmin.net/install-openjdk-java-ubuntu/).

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
```

#### 2. Download Apache Kafka

Download the Apache Kafka binary files from its official [download](https://kafka.apache.org/downloads) website. You can also select any nearby download mirror.

```
wget http://www-us.apache.org/dist/kafka/2.4.0/kafka_2.13-2.4.0.tgz
```

Then extract the archive file.

```
tar xzf kafka_2.13-2.4.0.tgz
mv kafka_2.13-2.4.0 /usr/local/kafka
```

Alternatively, download a binary from here:
https://kafka.apache.org/downloads

Note: installing from snap did not work on Ubuntu 22.04

#### 3. Setup Kafka systemd unit files

Next create systemd unit files for the Zookeeper and Kafka service. This will help to manage Kafka services to start/stop using the systemctl command.

First, create systemd unit file for Zookeeper with below command:

```
vim /etc/systemd/system/zookeeper.service
```

Add the below content:

```
[Unit]
Description=Apache Zookeeper server
Documentation=http://zookeeper.apache.org
Requires=network.target remote-fs.target
After=network.target remote-fs.target
[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/kafka/bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh /usr/local/kafka/config/zookeeper.properties
ExecStop=/usr/local/kafka/bin/zookeeper-server-stop.sh
Restart=on-abnormal
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Save the file and close it.

Next, to create a Kafka systemd unit file using the following command:

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/kafka.service
```

Add the below content. Make sure to set the correct `JAVA_HOME` path as per the Java installed on your system.

```
[Unit]
Description=Apache Kafka Server
Documentation=http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html
Requires=zookeeper.service
[Service]
Type=simple
Environment="JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64"
ExecStart=/usr/local/kafka/bin/kafka-server-start.sh /usr/local/kafka/config/server.properties
ExecStop=/usr/local/kafka/bin/kafka-server-stop.sh
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Save the file and close.

Reload the systemd daemon to apply the new changes.

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

#### 4. Start Kafka server

Kafka required ZooKeeper so first, start a ZooKeeper server on your system. You can use the script available with Kafka to get start a single-node ZooKeeper instance.

```
sudo systemctl start zookeeper
```

Now start the Kafka server and view the running status:

```
sudo systemctl start kafka
sudo systemctl status kafka
```

[image]

All done. The Kafka installation has been successfully completed. The next part of this answer will help you to work with the Kafka server.

#### 5. Create a topic in Kafka

Kafka provides multiple pre-built shell script to work on it. First, create a topic named "testTopic" with a single partition with single replica:

```
cd /usr/local/kafka
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic testTopic
Created topic testTopic.
```

The replication-factor describes how many copies of data will be created. As we are running with a single instance keep this value 1.

Set the partitions options as the number of brokers you want your data to be split between. As we are running with a single broker keep this value 1.

You can create multiple topics by running the same command as above. After that, you can see the created topics on Kafka by the running the below command:

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
testTopic
TecAdminTutorial1
TecAdminTutorial2
```

Alternatively instead of manually creating topics you can also configure your brokers to auto-create topics when a nonexistent topic is published to.

#### 6. Send messages to Kafka

The "producer" is the process responsible for putting data into our Kafka. Kafka comes with a command-line client that will take input from a file or from standard input and send it out as messages to the Kafka cluster. The default Kafka sends each line as a separate message.

Let's run the producer and then type a few messages into the console to send to the server.

```
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic testTopic

> Welcome to kafka
> This is my first topic
```

You can exit this command or keep this terminal running for further testing. Now open a new terminal to the Kafka consumer process on the next step.

#### 7. Using Kafka consumer

Kafka also has a command-line consumer to read data from the Kafka cluster and display messages to standard output.

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic testTopic --from-beginning
Welcome to kafka
This is my first topic
```

Now If you have still running Kafka producer (Step 6) in another terminal, just type some text on that producer terminal. It will immediately be visible on consumer terminal. See the below screenshot of Kafka producer and consumer working:

[image]

<sub>**Source:** [How to Install Apache Kafka on Ubuntu 18.04 & 16.04](https://web.archive.org/web/20200530102213/https://tecadmin.net/install-apache-kafka-ubuntu/)</sub>

Comment: ```kafka.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/local/kafka/bin/kafka-server-start.sh: No s```

Comment: zookeeper is also failing

Comment: @mLstudent33 Maybe my answer needs to be updated for Ubuntu 22.04. Please read this: [How to Install Apache Kafka on Ubuntu 22.04](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/ubuntu-apache-kafka-installation/)

Comment: Maybe try installing zookeeper with apt using `sudo apt install zookeeper`.

Comment: I downloaded 2.13 from here: https://kafka.apache.org/downloads and the rest of your instructions worked.  Thanks very much.

Comment: @mLstudent33 Please edit my answer by adding your modifications to my original instructions to it, and I will accept your suggested edit.